# Where in the documentation does it say that while tests readdir for definedness?

Tags: perl, perldoc

See also: [How is "0" result from readdir not false in a while condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843430/how-is-0-result-from-readdir-not-false-in-a-while-condition).  (*Not a duplicate; just closely related.*)

---

Where in the documentation does it say that while tests readdir for definedness?  For instance, this code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

opendir my $dir, "/tmp" or die "$!";

while (my $file = readdir($dir)) {
        print "$file\n";
}
closedir $dir;
```

when run through [B::Deparse](http://perldoc.perl.org/B/Deparse.html) yields:

```
use warnings;
use strict 'refs';
die "$!" unless opendir my $dir, '/tmp';
while (defined(my $file = readdir $dir)) {
    do {
        print "$file\n"
    };
}
z.pl syntax OK
```

I expect this behaviour, but I cannot find where it is specified.  In the [I/O Operators section of perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators) it says

> The following lines are equivalent:
>
> `while (defined($_ = <STDIN>)) { print; }`
>        `while ($_ = <STDIN>) { print; }`
>        `while (<STDIN>) { print; }`
>        `for (;<STDIN>;) { print; }`
>        `print while defined($_ = <STDIN>);`
>        `print while ($_ = <STDIN>);`
>        `print while <STDIN>;`

But there is no mention of `readdir`.

Comment: There was a closely related question earlier today - asking about why the loop doesn't stop on a file called '0' and running on MacOS X -- was that you?  Interesting discovery - it probably isn't documented except under the heading of Perl's general DWIM-iness.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler I answered that question, but I am not satisfied with my answer, so I asked a more direct question in the hopes that it will jog someone's memory.  I could swear I have seen it in the docs somewhere, but it may have been in Programming Perl or some other book.  Or I could just be imagining it.  If no one can find it in the docs I will probably submit a patch adding it to readdir's portion of perlfunc.  I don't like relying on undocumented behaviour.

Comment: BTW, this came about because I noticed a whole load of samples in "Higher Order Perl" that didn't have the defined() test.  I mailed the author saying "that's wrong".  He mailed back saying "no it isn't".

Comment: I would like to note that in [5.18](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5180delta.html#Selected-Bug-Fixes) that was also [applied](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/commit/8ae39f603f0f5778c160e18e08df60affbd5a620) to [`each`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html); which wouldn't make much sense to document in that [section](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators) of [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html).

Answer (score 6):

You're quite right about it being undocumented.  I've looked rather hard, and I can't find any reference to it being special either.  It *is* special, as you've discovered, and as demonstrated by:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse \
       -E'opendir(my $dir, "."); while($_ = readdir($dir)) { say; }'

BEGIN {
    $^H{'feature_say'} = q(1);
    $^H{'feature_state'} = q(1);
    $^H{'feature_switch'} = q(1);
}
opendir my $dir, '.';
while (defined($_ = readdir $dir)) {
    say $_;
}
-e syntax OK
```

Looking through the source, `Perl_newWHILEOP` in `op.c` specifically has tests for `readdir`, `glob`, `readline` and `each`... Hmm, let's do some digging, and see when `readdir` was added.

A bit of digging with `git` reveals that it's been that way since at least 1998, with Gurusamy Sarathy making the relevant change in commit `55d729e4`.  While I haven't gone digging to see which releases that's gone into, I'd wager it would be at least 5.6.0 and above.  I can't find any mention of it in the deltas.

It *might* be mentioned in the third edition camel book, but I haven't checked to find out.

I think that a patch here (or even just a note to p5p) would certainly be appreciated.

*Paul*

Comment: Interesting, glob in while does get tested for definedness, but bsd_glob in while does not.  Looks like it is time for a document patch.

Comment: see also the counter example in my question, where you can fool Perl's DWIM logic if the call to readdir() is not directly in the while() loop but in a function called in the while() test.

Comment: Actually the [`readdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) check was only [added in 2009 to 5.12 with commit 114c60ecb1f775ef1deb4fdc8fb8e3a6f343d13d](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/commit/114c60ecb1f775ef1deb4fdc8fb8e3a6f343d13d). It was extended to [`each`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html) [in 2012 to 5.18 with commit 8ae39f603f0f5778c160e18e08df60affbd5a620](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/commit/8ae39f603f0f5778c160e18e08df60affbd5a620).

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry that I didn't think to update the pages that you expected to find this information.

I did add a note to the [`readdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) section of [`perlfunc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#readdir-DIRHANDLE) though.

> As of Perl 5.12 you can use a bare `readdir` in a `while` loop, which will
>   set `$_` on every iteration.
>
> ```
> opendir(my $dh, $some_dir) || die;
> while(readdir $dh) {
>     print "$some_dir/$_\n";
> }
> closedir $dh;
> ```

It doesn't explicitly say that it checks for definedness though.

( I would like to note that adding this feature was my first patch to the Perl core. )